# display category list year wise in wordpress

Tags: categories, archives

I want to display those categories which have post year-wise.
Example:

2016

```
     category 1 
     category 2
     category 3
```

(on click of category 1, post from category 1 + year 2016 will display, means filter with category name + year is applied)

```
     2015
     category 2
```

Any Help is highly appreciable. Thanxs.

Answer (score 1):

```
function extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array();
    $structures = array(
        $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_date_permastruct(),
        $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_month_permastruct(),
        $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_year_permastruct(),
    );
    foreach( $structures as $s ){
        $rules += $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($s);
    }
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules');
```

add this code to your functions.php 
check this url http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/wordpress-category-archives-by-date/

Comment: my ques is not clear to u? I am looking to display "category list", year wise, I already check the above plugin, but it display the "post list "year wise not category link. Anyways thnxx :)

Comment: now have you check this plugin :https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-archive/screenshots/